# CustomUserControl Double Click Event in ControlTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, xceed-datagrid

In WPF I created a CustomUserControl with DoubleClick event handler. I am using this control inside ControlTemplate in this way:

```
             <xcdg:DataCell FieldName="."  Template="{StaticResource myTemplate}">
                </xcdg:DataCell>
```

And also this my ControlTemplate:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" TargetType="xcdg:DataCell">
                        <uicontrols:MyCustomControl  Tag="{Binding ID}"  Margin="0"  Height="140" Width="150" DoubleClick="ctrl_DoubleClick">
    </ControlTemplate>
```

DoubleClick event handler is not working inside the ControlTemplate. what is the problem and what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found out my answer. rather than using extra template in DateCell. I used inline template.

```
<xcdg:DataCell FieldName=".">
 <xcdg:DataCell.Template>
   <ControlTemplate> 
     // your template code. here the event of my controls are working.
   </ControlTemplate>
 </xcdg:DataCell.Template>
</xcdg:DataCell>
```